# send auto response through php form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to make it so if the e-mail sends successfully the `$email`will get a automatic response from the `$mail_to` preferably with HTML signature included.

CODE:

```
<?php  

    $mail_to = 'REMOVED@EMAILERE.com'; 

    // specify your email here     //    
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email'];     
    $reason = $_POST['reason'];     
    $message = $_POST['message'];  

    // Construct email subject     
    $subject = 'Enquiry Form Submission';    

    $body_message .= 'Stage Name: ' . $name . "\r\n";   
    $body_message .= 'E-mail Address: ' . $email . "\r\n";     
    $body_message .= 'Reason for Contacting: ' . $reason . "\r\n";     
    $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= "IP Address: " . getUserIpAddr();

    // Construct email headers  
    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n";     
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n";     

    $mail_sent = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);     

    if ($mail_sent == true){ 
?>         
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">                 
    window.location = 'http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/forms/success';        
</script>       
<?php     
    } 
?>
<?php

function getUserIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) //if from shared
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //if from a proxy
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: and the problem/question is?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to pass the user information to another PHP page (`http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/forms/success`), form the URL using GET parameters (e.g., `http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/forms/success?ip=$ip`). But honestly, I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Note: `PHP mail()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but it does NOT tell you whether the email was delivered successfully. This just is not possible in PHP.

From PHP documentation on `mail()`:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Comment: I am trying to make it so it's an automatic response, so if the form submission is sent successfully to my e-mail they will get an automated reply as soon as it's sent